# SQL Server - Mirroring from 2014 to 2017 check unsent log status

Tags: sql-server-2014, mirroring

I configured SQL Server Mirroring from SQL server 2014 standard to SQL Server 2017 Enterprise.

Steps I followed:

1. Create an endpoint on both servers with certificate authentication.
2. Dump and restored.
3. On secondary - `alter db set partner ='TCP://primary:5022'`
4. On Primary - `alter db set partner ='TCP://secondary:5022'`

Now the mirroring setup is done.

I know it's not officially recommended but using TSQL we can achieve this.

I can see the status of this mirroring is in Syncrozied state. But in `sp_dbmmonitorresults` its showing NULL.

Is there anyway that I can see the Unsent log/Unrestored Log status?

Comment: What is status of mirror database?

Comment: Mirror and syncronized